# Custom interop assembly crashes Excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I made custom office interop assemblies by tlbimp and application is using this assemblies instead of MS PIA assemblies (MS has strange behaviour to this assemblies for last months). Dev computer is working well but we found twp pc, where these new assemblies crashing excel via ExecutionEngineException in clr.dll and I cannot find any reason for crash. dnSpy reporing crash at `if (((worksheet != null) ? worksheet.AutoFilter : null) == null).` IL Code for PIA and custom assemblies seems not to be too much different. Did anybody has been solving this problem or using custom office interop assemblies ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, AutoFilter is not always AutoFilter by dispid for older versions of excel, but why this crashed clr.dll instead of DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND I did found.